# jQuery - targeting <a> elements whose hrefs point to images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I target all `<a>` elements whose `href`s point to image files? For the sake of keeping it simple, it could simply target all `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.png` and `.gif` files.

Example HTML:

```
<a href="file1.jpg">file1</a>
<a href="file2.png">file2</a>
<a href="file3.zip">file3</a>
```

Running jQuery:

```
$(target).remove();
```

Should produce:

```
<a href="file3.zip">file3</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this with the help of attribute selector

```
$('a[href$=jpg],a[href$=png]').remove();
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/EwCz2/)</kbd>

[**Documentation : http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

Comment: Would this work even for the following? ``<a href="file1.jpg?rev=2">file</a>``

Comment: in that case use `$('a[href*=jpg],a[href*=png]').remove();`

Comment: @RichardRodriguez no, and it won't work for URLs that respond with an image but don't contain anything that looks like a common image file extension. It's not a problem you can solve with 100% reliability on the client.

Comment: Would that properly handle the following? ``<a href="file1.jpg.zip?rev=2">file</a>``

Comment: @Pointy: I don't care about those cases and I'm fully aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

Regex solution:

```
$("a").each(function() {
    if ( $(this).attr("href").match(/\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)(?:\?(.*))?$/) ) {;
        $(this).remove();
    }
})
```

Comment: What about ``<a href="file1.jpg.zip?rev=2">file</a>`` ?

Comment: @user3362707 I think that "file.jpg?rev=2" should be included in the set of `<a>` elements to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited** You can achieve that with this. Each comma-separated selector target a file type

```
var imageLinks = $('a[href*=".jpg"], a[href*=".jpeg"], a[href*=".png"], a[href*=".gif"]');
```

you should read this: [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: This wouldn't work for ``<a href="file1.jpg?rev=2">file</a>``

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to get rid of `<a>` elements that involve "href" attributes containing paths that *look like* common image filenames, I think you'll have to use `.filter()` and a regular expression.

```
$('a').filter(function() {
  return /\.(?:jpg|png|gif)(?:\?.*)?$/i.test(this.href);
}).remove();
```